# mongo (3.2): Backing up with fsyncLock() files still being modified on the filesystem

Tags: mongodb, copy, backup

When backing up the mongo file system using tar, using a secondary in a replication set, tar is saying files have changed during the tar process even though the lock command has been run. For reliable backups this should not happen. What I am missing?

```
devtest:SECONDARY> use admin
switched to db admin
devtest:SECONDARY> db.fsyncLock()
{
        "info" : "now locked against writes, use db.fsyncUnlock() to unlock",
        "seeAlso" : "http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/fsynccommand",
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Using the find command looking for changed files while the tar process is running confirms this. Comparing before and after versions of these files with diff also confirms. It appears to always be these files.

```
/var/lib/mongo # find -cmin 1
.
./WiredTiger.turtle
./WiredTiger.wt
./diagnostic.data
./diagnostic.data/metrics.interim
```

Using Mongo 3.2 and wiredtiger configured.

```
/etc/mongo.conf
storage:
  directoryPerDB: true
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  engine: "wiredTiger"
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      directoryForIndexes: true
    collectionConfig:
      blockCompressor: snappy
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

Documentation seems to imply files will not be changed. Maybe only "data" files will not change...

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/

> Changed in version 3.2: db.fsyncLock() can ensure that the data files do not change for MongoDB instances using either the MMAPv1 or the WiredTiger storage engines, thus providing consistency for the purposes of creating backups.
>
> In previous MongoDB versions, db.fsyncLock() cannot guarantee a consistent set of files for low-level backups (e.g. via file copy cp, scp, tar) for WiredTiger.

Comment: You should avoid tarring the files directly on the volume containing the mongodb data directory. Instead have the directory on LVM, and use LVM snapshots, then build the tarball from the data directory in the snapshot filesystem. It's a matter of seconds to create the snapshot, and you can then immediately fsyncUnlock(), plus you won't encounter the error you're encountering with tar: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/

Comment: Why should I avoid tarring on the volume? Documentation seems to say locking the db will stop writes the file system. I agree the LVM way is preferred but setting up LVM is an overhead I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Edit: Added reference to documentation for fsyncLock

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing mongodb still needs to continue saving data while it's running, but from what you say it seems safe to backup your data as nothing is changing your collection data.

However if you're unsure you could always `db.shutdownServer()` which will force a flush to disk and stop the service, then back it up then start the mongod process again.

Comment: Since this is a file system backup I concerned about the changing of any files.

If I find no resolution to my issue stopping the server seems the only way. Not want I want. This would generate alert emails on our system.

Comment: `db.shutdownServer()` will only shutdown the mongod service, but agree'd it isn't ideal getting false alerts from monitoring